# Unable to access function from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules, plop

I'm trying to implement the plop.js micro framework, but the setGenerator method is always unresolved.
I've executed following commands

```
npm install --save-dev plop
npm install -g plop
```

I also enabled Coding assistance for Node.js in Webstorm (v2019 3.3), still the methods are inaccessible

```
module.exports = function(plop)  {
plop.setGenerator('component', {
    description: 'Create a component',
    prompts: [
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'name',
            message: 'What is your component name?'
        },
    ],
    actions: [
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: 'src/scenes/screens/{{camelCase name}}/index.js',
            templateFile: 'src/services/dev/plop-templates/index.js.hbs',
        }
    ]
});
};
```

This file is located in the root of my project like suggested inside the documentation.

Is there any other way to access it from the node_modules?

Comment: If im understanding correctly you're trying to access a custom node module from your file system. You can install it like: `npm install -D plop@"./path/to/module"`

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed it by reinstalling the node_modules